# Running puppet on a single machine using a vagrant produced cluster

Tags: virtual-machines, puppet, vagrant

I am building a four cluster machine with Vagrant and provisioning those machines using puppet.

I want to find a way to get my puppet scripts to only run on an individual machine. As it stands right now, each puppet script runs identically on every machine.

Here's my Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.define "Greenplum setup"
  config.vm.box = "lucid64"

config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v, override|
  override.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/lucid64.box"
  v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "256"]
end

config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
  puppet.manifests_path = "manifests"
  puppet.manifest_file  = "base-hadoop.pp"
  puppet.module_path = "modules"
end

config.vm.define :smdw do |smdw_config|
  smdw_config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.2.11"
  smdw_config.vm.hostname = "smdw"
end

config.vm.define :sdw1 do |sdw1_config|
  sdw1_config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.2.12"
  sdw1_config.vm.hostname = "sdw1"
end

config.vm.define :sdw2 do |sdw2_config|
  sdw2_config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.2.13"
  sdw2_config.vm.hostname = "sdw2"
end

 config.vm.define :mdw do |mdw_config|
  mdw_config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.2.10"
  mdw_config.vm.hostname = "mdw"
end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you move the puppet definition inside the block for the host you want to run puppet against, it will run only on that host.  I use a similar method to define a cluster with a puppetmaster and several puppet agents.

Here is a quick example assuming that this would be for your smdw_config host.  Remove the puppet stanza and change the smdw_config stanza as below:

```
config.vm.define :smdw do |smdw_config|
  smdw_config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.2.11"
  smdw_config.vm.hostname = "smdw"
  smdw_config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
    puppet.options        = '-d -v'
    puppet.manifests_path = "manifests"
    puppet.manifest_file  = "base-hadoop.pp"
    puppet.module_path = "modules"
  end
end
```

BTW I usually add the debug and verbose options to providers if available.